# Importing data, then plotting ListPlot. What's the most efficient way to write a code?

Tags: plotting, matrix, function-construction, map

It should be a boring question to ask for someone, but this is very basic need which I haven't resolved by myself. I know I can use MapThread and pure function to make it short and beautiful, but even though I tried, I haven't been successful yet.

Here is the code. Basically, I'd like to get data and plot them. How would you write it in a efficient and elegant way? Any help will be very appreciable. So, I can keep learning.

```
data = {{"Anneal Temp", "L/L0", "L/L0", "L/L0", "L/L0", 
    "L/L0"}, {"C\\+(o)", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%"}, {"Anneal Temp", 
    "25C", "40C", "50C", "60C", "25C_HP"}, {25.`, 100.`, 100.`, 100.`,
     100.`, 100.`}, {400.`, 94.10705`, 96.7285`, 96.58404`, 96.79382`,
     97.32171`}, {600.`, 92.67395`, 95.23963`, 94.87605`, 95.48717`, 
    92.52326`}, {800.`, 82.6344`, 86.78122`, 87.94923`, 89.8549`, 
    85.86822`}, {1000.`, 55.62473`, 61.00761`, 61.45969`, 63.37078`, 
    65.06202`}};

x = data[[4 ;;, 1]];
y1 = data[[4 ;;, 2]];
y2 = data[[4 ;;, 3]];
y3 = data[[4 ;;, 4]];
y4 = data[[4 ;;, 5]];
y5 = data[[4 ;;, 6]];

p1 = Thread[{x, y1}];
p2 = Thread[{x, y2}];
p3 = Thread[{x, y3}];
p4 = Thread[{x, y4}];
p5 = Thread[{x, y5}];

ListLinePlot[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ListLinePlot@Inner[List, data[[4 ;;, 1]], data[[4 ;;, 2 ;;]], List]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi Dr. Belisarius, this is what I was looking for. Something short and simple. I need to study through. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{"Anneal Temp", "L/L0", "L/L0", "L/L0", "L/L0", 
    "L/L0"}, {"C\\+(o)", "%", "%", "%", "%", "%"}, {"Anneal Temp", 
    "25C", "40C", "50C", "60C", "25C_HP"}, {25.`, 100.`, 100.`, 100.`,
     100.`, 100.`}, {400.`, 94.10705`, 96.7285`, 96.58404`, 96.79382`,
     97.32171`}, {600.`, 92.67395`, 95.23963`, 94.87605`, 95.48717`, 
    92.52326`}, {800.`, 82.6344`, 86.78122`, 87.94923`, 89.8549`, 
    85.86822`}, {1000.`, 55.62473`, 61.00761`, 61.45969`, 63.37078`, 
    65.06202`}};

ListLinePlot[
 data[[4 ;;, {1, #}]] & /@ Range[2, 6],
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 PlotLegends -> Rest@data[[3]],
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14] & /@
    {data[[1, 1]], 
     data[[1, 2]] <> " " <> data[[2, 2]]})]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bob, Thank you for much for your help. Your response is really useful for  me. I appreciate it.